# Seleccionar ítem treeview con notebook

Tags: python, tkinter

querida comunidad.
Estoy teniendo un inconveniente intentando seleccionar ítems en un treeview y me he dado cuenta que todo surge por los estilos.

El código de la vista es el siguiente:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

import modelo


root=tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("1200x660")

style = ttk.Style()
settings = {"TNotebook.Tab": {"configure": {"padding": [5, 1],
                                            "background": "deep pink"   
                                           },
                              "map": {"background": [("selected", "pink"),
                                                     ("active", "hot pink")],
                                      "foreground": [("selected", "gray26"), 
                                                     ("active", "#ffffff")], 
                                     }
                              }
           }

style.theme_create("mi_estilo", parent="alt", settings=settings)
style.theme_use("mi_estilo")

hojas = ttk.Notebook(root)
hojas.pack(fill="both", expand="yes")

pesta0 = tkinter.Frame(hojas, background="pink")

hojas.add(pesta0, text="Catálogo")

tree = ttk.Treeview(pesta0)
tree["columns"] = ("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5")

tree.column("#0", width=40)
tree.column("#1", width=420, anchor="center")
tree.column("#2", width=300, anchor="center")
tree.column("#3", width=250, anchor="center")
tree.column("#4", width=95, anchor="center")
tree.column("#5", width=65, anchor="center")


tree.heading("#0", text="Id #", anchor="center")
tree.heading("#1", text="COSA1", anchor="center")
tree.heading("#2", text="COSA2", anchor="center")
tree.heading("#3", text="COSA3", anchor="center")
tree.heading("#4", text="COSA4", anchor="center")
tree.heading("#5", text="COSA5", anchor="center")

tree.place(x=10, y=400, height=100)

consxest = tkinter.Button(pesta0, text="Estado", background="light pink", foreground="DeepPink4", font=("Courier", 11, "bold"), command= lambda: modelo.consxestado(tree))
consxest.place(x=240, y=270)

root.mainloop()
```

Y el código del modelo es:

```
def consxestado(tree):
tree.insert("", "end", text="0", values=("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
tree.insert("", "end", text="6", values=("7", "8", "9", "10", "11"))
```

Me he dado cuenta que comentando la línea *style.theme_use("mi_estilo")* (o sea, quitándole el estilo) en la vista, me permite seleccionar ítems del tree. Pero si lo dejo como está, no.
Les pido ayuda porque no sé cómo solucionarlo.